# using c++0x - safe?

Tags: c++, c++11, hashmap

I wanted to use an stl hashmap, and as among other things i found c++ doesn't have it, but c++0x does - so as someone who is not up to date - is c++0x safe to use? (Is it already fully tested and can be counted on to be relatively bug free?). If so - it seems like there are a lot of newer versions (c++11) - should i use them, or maybe they are still not reliable enough.  Actually anyway when i try to use something from the new interface, my linux compiler tells me that i have to include c++0x - so i guess my compiler isn't up to date enoug

Comment: What does *safe* mean to you? C++ programs are not safe; they can and do crash. A strongly typed language like Ocaml or Haskell is safer.

Comment: GCC 4.6 has support for C++0x.

Comment: C++11 is a standard (that is to say, a PDF document), not an actual implementation that could "be tested" or "have bugs". Assuming your linux compiler is GCC, it supports various parts of C++11. Use `--std=c++0x` to switch on this partial support. What's there probably isn't *very* buggy, but it doesn't necessarily conform to the standard. So if you consider a missing feature to be a bug, then it's buggy.

Comment: You can check for support of the c++0x by various compilers here : http://wiki.apache.org/stdcxx/C++0xCompilerSupport

Comment: Actually the fact that your linux compiler tells you you have to include c++0x means it **is** up to date enough. If it wasn't, it would simply tell you it does not know what `unordered_map` means.

Comment: @Basile : C++ is also strongly typed, it just has `void*` as a loophole.

Comment: @Ildjarm: No C++ is not safe: `void f(int y) {int* x = nullptr; if (y*y == 3) x=new int; *x = 13;}` don't get any warnings by compiler, and crashes for all calls to `f`. So C++11 is not safe. You can't write in the safe portion of Ocaml (without `Obj.magic`, which is very rarely used) a program that compiles without warnings and crashes.

Comment: @Basile : I didn't use the word "safe", I said "strongly typed" -- C++ _is_ strongly typed.

Comment: I did use the word safe, and I explained you why Ocaml is IMHO safer than C++, because it is more strongly typed.

Comment: @Basile : I'm just going to assume this is a translation issue and leave it alone. ;-]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is supposed to be safe for non safety-critical applications. I think that there is no safety-critical compiler with C++0x support yet.

But, for desktop applications, you should have no problems with that. But note that just a few compilers support C++0x (afak gcc 4.6+ and VC 2010), and they don't support all the functionalities. It is important that you read the compiler specifications to check what they support and what they don't.

I would prefer to wait a newer release of these compilers to use it in commercial apps.

Comment: For gcc it's not 4.6 in particular. Gcc adds individual bits of c++11 gradually. First c++11 features appeared already in 4.3 and 4.7 still does not support all of them. Plus gcc may be used also with other implementation of standard library than GNU stdlibc++, so some other features depend on which library you are using.

Answer (score 6):

C++0x was the working title of C++11.

Look up your compiler version in the [c++11](/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b11) tag [info](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/c++11/info) page to learn about its support for new features.

Long story short: GCC is well ahead of the pack but still doesn't have 100% of the features. Some things <s>such as user-defined literals</s> are not yet supported by any compiler. (**Edit:** I'm not sure, but I think some features of regular expressions and the atomic memory model fall into this category.) Essential features such as rvalue references are widely complete.

`std::unordered_map` was introduced by C++03 TR1, and is supported by all C++11 implementations and also all modern C++03 implementations through their TR1 libraries, even without C++11 language support. Under TR1, the template is called `std::tr1::unordered_map`, and you might have to take some platform-specific step to enable TR1, such as adding some `tr1/` subdirectory to the include file search paths.

Comment: Actually, GCC does support user-defined literals, see [GCC 4.7 C++11 status](http://gcc.gnu.org/gcc-4.7/cxx0x_status.html).

Comment: @Basile: … and all C++11 support in GCC is labelled "experimental." In practice, going to the bleeding edge compiler is likely to fix more problems than it creates, especially when using bleeding-edge C++ constructs. (But `unordered_map` shouldn't require C++11 or any upgrade at all. Confusing choice of accepted answer, here…)

Answer (score 2):

Yes, it should be safe. But - like you've already seen - only part of C++11 standard is implemented in various compilators. Try to get the newest gcc, it implements majority of C++11 features: http://gcc.gnu.org/projects/cxx0x.html

Answer (score 1):

There is no C++0x. That was a working name for what has finally become C++11 on 12 August 2011.

The standard contains many parts that were drafted separately and compilers started supporting them individually even before the standard was finalized, but on the other hand some parts are not yet supported at all. So you need to check whether your compiler supports the features you want to use.

Now the particular case of `std::unordered_map`, it was first standardized in [C++ TR1](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C%2B%2B_Technical_Report_1), but originates long before that in [boost](http://boost.org). Most compilers that don't support C++11 do support TR1, so `std::tr1::unordered_map` will be there and you can always take it from boost for those that don't.

As for gcc, the error is that you need to *enable* C++11. That is done by simply adding `-std=c++0x` option to the compiler command-line. This is done so that you don't accidentally use C++11 feature in code you still care about portability to C++03 compilers.

Comment: Before Boost, it was in STL… as OP mentioned :vP . Note that different compilers access TR1 differently, so in GCC `#include <tr1/unordered_map>` is required, in MSVC it would be `#include <unordered_map>`, and for others it helps to RTFM.

Comment: @Potatoswatter: `unordered_map` was never in STL and while most implementations of "STL" include some `hashmap` class, they are mutually incompatible (e.g. Microsoft's version requires the keys to be ordered etc.).

Comment: STL is the name of a particular implementation which begat the standard container library. See the copyright info in your headers… it probably mentions HP and SGI. My copy of GCC 4.7 still provides `hash_map` in the `backward/` directory, and it still says copyright SGI, making it part of the STL.

Comment: @Potatoswatter: `hash_map` is part of STL. I am not sure it is fully compatible with `unordered_map` (which definitely wasn't part of STL) and I am certain there are variants of `hash_map` (in implementations of "STL", i.e. libraries reimplementing the original STL) incompatible with the STL one, which is part of the reason why TR1 introduced the new name.

Comment: Yes, TR1 introduced the new name… yet you said, the template "originates long before that in boost." The origin is long before Boost. Anyway, I think we both understand the history.